# Is there any way to check email domain validity on android?

Tags: android, validation, email, dns

I would like to find out, if there is a way to check email domain validity on android. And I am not asking about this kind of check -

`android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();`

I want to know if domain is valid, because sometimes user can make mistake and instead of `xxx@gmail.com` he will write `xxx@gmal.com`, etc.. Thanks

Comment: This Kind of perfect validation not exist in the world. Because Any domain name possible.

Comment: your can try some online api services for that.example: https://verify-email.org/faq.html

Comment: Okay, I found my answer. if someone is also struggling with this issue, just use DNSjava library -> http://www.dnsjava.org/. If user has device with android SDK > O, than you need to use NetworkRequest, because of some changes in privacy -> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.

Answer (score -1):

I think below android library solve your problem,

See [AutoCompleteEmail](https://github.com/tikivn/AutoCompleteEmail) library from github.

```
1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

dependencies {
        compile 'vn.tiki.widgets:autocompleteemail:1.0.1'
}

2. Usage In your folder values create arrays.xml

<resources>
  <string-array name="domains">
    <item>gmail.com</item>
    <item>yahoo.com</item>
    <item>tiki.vn</item>
    <item>hotmail.com</item>
    <item>co.jp</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>

3. In your layout XML

 <vn.tiki.widgets.AutoCompleteEmailEditText
              android:id="@+id/etEmail"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
              app:domains="@array/domains"/>
```

Happy Coding:)

Comment: Thx, but this is not a solution i am looking for. 5 defined domains are not enough. There are a lot of domains in the world, you cant just use them in array.

Comment: @Segi, Ok but it can help you to use as a **Top** or **most common ** used domain world wide.